# How can i set a child term while creating a post from frontend?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I've created a form in frontend part , which users can add vehicle listings and all related vehicle information .

I've created a taxonomy called "vehicle_make" and inside that taxonomy I've added categories like this from backend .

- Audi

  - A5
  - A7
- Mercedes

  - e320
  - s500

So user have to select a Make first then Model number will show up. Which I managed to do this and can get both Make $_POST slug value and Model $_POST slug value without a problem .

Now after I check user $_POST , I can save all other information , I can set the Make "AUDI" as term , but cannot set "A5" or "A7" as child of that term .

I've tried this code ..

```
<pre>


if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) && isset( $_POST['hidden'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['hidden'], 'hidden' ) ) {



  if ( trim( $_POST['listing_vehicle_make'] ) != '' ) 
        // This will store Vehicle Make Slug
        $listing_vehicle_make_slug = $_POST['listing_vehicle_make'];


   if ( trim( $_POST['listing_vehicle_model'] ) != '' )
        // This will store vehicle model slug
        $listing_vehicle_model_slug = $_POST['listing_vehicle_model'];


$post = array(
            'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $listing_title ),
            'post_content' => $listing_description, // Didn't add the code
            'post_status' => 'pending', // Didn't add the code
            'post_type' => 'vehicles'  // Didn't add the code
        );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $listing_vehicle_make_slug , 'vehicle_make');


 </pre>
```

I've googled for many hours now and couldn't find something that I thought it would help me .

If anyone can contribute it would help me a lot guys .

Thank you .

Comment: Hi, just in case, did you set the taxonomy "vehicle_make" as hierarchical (like category) ? Tags are not hierarchical, if you want to stay with, you can use wp_set_object_terms two time for the model and its parent. Can you edit your question with the register_taxonomy arg ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `wp_set_object_terms` function is very tricky as it can returns error for many reasons and pretty hard to debug from my experience.

However you can try a few things to make it work, first take a look on the returned value :

```
$set_terms = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $listing_vehicle_make_slug , 'vehicle_make');
print_r($set_terms);
```

So you can understand what's the error.

Another advice, which we actually use a lot (I'm creating frontend exclusive WP theme) is to set the terms by ID and not by slug. It'll work much more easily.

Here is the idea :

```
// We get the term's object : 
$type_catgeory_object = get_term_by( 'slug', $listing_vehicle_make_slug, 'vehicle_make');

// If we find something : 
if($type_catgeory_object != false){
   // Get its id : 
   $term_id = $type_catgeory_object->id;
   // Add it : 
   $value_set = wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array($term_id), 'vehicle_make');
}
```

More details can be found on the doc : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms

Comment: Didn't have time working on this project for so long , remembered your answer and combined it with my custom plugin for makes and it worked . 

Cheers man , thanks a lot .

Comment: No problem, feel free to validate it for other users ;)